# Rabbitpy listener reading from wrong queue

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I am trying to run a program that uses rabbitpy to send commands from the terminal on one queue and read responses in a separate thread on a different queue. The problem is that when I send a message on queue1, my listener thread (which should be listening on queue2, not queue1) reads/consumes the message from queue1. Below is my code. The constants in all caps are just string constants, and mqsetup just sets up the queues and routine keys to make sure they exist. What am I doing wrong?

```
 ####################################################################
 # dummy_ctrl.py
 # This is a dummy script that acts like a controller. It lets a
 # user/tester send task requests to our task handler thread pool
 # and get results back
 ####################################################################
 import threading
 import json
 import rabbitpy
 import mqsetup
 import traceback

 from constants import (
     AMQP_URL,
     CTRL_EXCHANGE,
     CTRL_QUEUE,
     CTRL_RESPONSE_QUEUE,
     CTRL_ROUTING_KEY,
     CTRL_RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY
 )

 #
 # This class listens for responses from our task thread pool program
 # When it gets a response message it just prints it
 #
 class MQResponseListener(object):
     def __init__(self,queue_name=CTRL_RESPONSE_QUEUE):
         self.queue_name=queue_name
         self.running=False
         self.conn=None
         self.channel=None
         self.exchange=None
         self.queue=None

     #
     # This is the listener function that runs in an infinite loop in a thread.
     # It keeps going until the user stops it with a stop call
     #
     def run_listener(self):
         print "Running listener"
         with rabbitpy.Connection(AMQP_URL) as self.conn:
             # Open the channel to communicate with RabbitMQ
             print "Got self.conn"
             with self.conn.channel() as self.channel:
                 print "Got self.channel"
                 self.queue = rabbitpy.Queue(self.channel, self.queue_name)
                 print "Got self.queue on queue name %s" % self.queue_name
                 print "Finished listener setup, now wait for messages"

                 for message in self.queue.consume():
                     if message:
                         print "***********************************************************************"
                         print "Received Message!"
                         print "***********************************************************************"
                         print "Message body is %s" % message.body
                         message.ack()
                         print "Waiting for next message"
                     else:
                         print "Message is None, did we just call stop consuming?"
                         break
                 print "Finished consuming"

         print "End of run_listener"

     #
     # This launches the listener as a thread and then returns
     # The thread will run forever (persistent listener)
     #
     def start(self):
         self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.run_listener)
         self.running=True
         print "Starting listener"
         self.thread.start()

     def stop(self):
         print "stopping consuming"
         self.running=False
         self.queue.stop_consuming()
         print "end of listener.stop()"

     def join(self):
         self.thread.join()

 def publish_message(channel,body_value):
     #
     # Create the message to publish
     #
     message = rabbitpy.Message(channel, body_value)

     #
     # Publish the message, looking for the return value to be a bool True/False
     #
     if message.publish(CTRL_EXCHANGE, routing_key=CTRL_ROUTING_KEY, mandatory=True):
         print 'Message publish confirmed by RabbitMQ'
     else:
         print 'RabbitMQ indicates message publishing failure'

 if __name__ == '__main__':

     mqsetup.setup()

     listener=MQResponseListener()
     listener.start()

     with rabbitpy.Connection(AMQP_URL) as conn:
         # Open the channel to communicate with RabbitMQ
         with conn.channel() as channel:

             exchange = rabbitpy.Exchange(channel, CTRL_EXCHANGE, exchange_type='direct')
             exchange.declare()

             # Turn on publisher confirmations
             channel.enable_publisher_confirms()

             queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, CTRL_QUEUE)
             queue.durable = True
             queue.declare()

             queue.bind(exchange, routing_key=CTRL_ROUTING_KEY)

             #queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, CTRL_QUEUE)

             while True:
                 print "Options:"
                 print "1. Call function some_dummy_command"
                 print "2. Quit"
                 try:
                     opt=int(raw_input('Select option number:'))
                     if opt==1:
                         #
                         # create message body in cmdstr
                         #
                         print "Sending a message"
                         cmdDict={
                             'ids': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
                             'name': "some_dummy_command",
                             'args': [],
                             'kwargs': {}
                         }
                         cmdstr=json.dumps(cmdDict)
                         #
                         # publish message on channel
                         #
                         publish_message(channel,cmdstr)
                     elif opt==2:
                         print "Stopping the listener"
                         listener.stop()
                         print "Breaking"
                         break
                     else:
                         print "opt unknown: %s" % opt

                 except rabbitpy.exceptions.NotConsumingError:
                     break
                 except ValueError:
                     print "Not a number"

     print "Waiting for listener thread to complete"
     listener.join()
     print "Done!"

 ####################################################################################
 # mqsetup.py
 # This module makes sure the exchanges, queues, etc all get set up in RabbitMQ.
 # This is crucial if not already set up, has no effect if they are already set up.
 ####################################################################################
 import rabbitpy
 from constants import (
     AMQP_URL,
     CTRL_EXCHANGE,
     CTRL_QUEUE,
     CTRL_RESPONSE_QUEUE,
     CTRL_ROUTING_KEY,
     CTRL_RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY
 )

 def setup():
     # Connect to RabbitMQ on localhost, port 5672 as guest/guest
     conn=rabbitpy.Connection(AMQP_URL)
     channel=conn.channel()

     exchange = rabbitpy.Exchange(channel, CTRL_EXCHANGE, exchange_type='direct')
     exchange.declare()

     queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, CTRL_QUEUE)
     queue.durable = True
     queue.declare()
     queue.bind(exchange, routing_key=CTRL_ROUTING_KEY)

     channel.close()
     conn.close()

     #########

     # Connect to RabbitMQ on localhost, port 5672 as guest/guest
     conn=rabbitpy.Connection(AMQP_URL)
     channel=conn.channel()

     exchange = rabbitpy.Exchange(channel, CTRL_EXCHANGE, exchange_type='direct')
     exchange.declare()

     queue2 = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, CTRL_RESPONSE_QUEUE)
     queue2.durable = True
     queue2.declare()
     queue2.bind(exchange, routing_key=CTRL_RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY)

     channel.close()
     conn.close()
```

Comment: Note that when I create the exchange I use exchange_type='direct'. Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad. Originally my exchange was fanout. Later I changed it to direct, but I didn't restart the rabbitmq-server, and it still didn't work. So the key is to set the exchange to direct and restart the server. Now it works as expected.